# 04098. "trigger '%s.%s' is invalid and failed re-validation"

Tags: oracle, plsql

I would like to write a trigger which blocks deleting records from table and blocks decreasing salary on update. It works well as two seperate triggers, but I would like to merge it into one.

Here is my trigger after merging:

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER test
    BEFORE DELETE OR UPDATE
    ON emp
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
      IF UPDATING THEN
        IF :NEW.sal < :OLD.sal THEN
          raise_application_error(-20500, 'You cannot decrease emp salary');
        END IF;
      ELSE DELETING THEN
        raise_application_error(-20500, 'You cannot delete records from emp');
      END IF;
    END;
```

The problem is when I try to update or delete record I get an error:

```
04098. 00000 -  "trigger '%s.%s' is invalid and failed re-validation"
*Cause:    A trigger was attempted to be retrieved for execution and was
           found to be invalid.  This also means that compilation/authorization
           failed for the trigger
```

I think that there is a problem around this line - `BEFORE DELETE OR UPDATE` because as I know if I `FOR EACH ROW` statment I should write is as `BEFORE UPDATE on sal`, but then I don't know how to join `BEFORE DELETE` statment into this.

EDIT: 
Problem was around `ELSE` statment. It should be changed to `ELSIF`

Comment: Please try to replace `else` with `elsif` (or remove `deleting then`).

Comment: You are 100% right, I have totally missed it.

Comment: I would do anything to make your trigger work, as it forbids salary reductions. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your IF statement syntax is incorrect. It should be:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER test
  BEFORE DELETE OR UPDATE
  ON emp
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF UPDATING AND :NEW.sal < :OLD.sal THEN
    raise_application_error(-20500, 'You cannot decrease emp salary');
  ELSIF DELETING THEN
    raise_application_error(-20500, 'You cannot delete records from emp');
  END IF;
END test;
```

I also combined the two IF statements used in the UPDATING case into one to keep it simpler.

**EDIT**

In the case where you don't want to allow salaries to be decreased another possible solution is to quietly change the salary back to its original value, as in:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER test
  BEFORE DELETE OR UPDATE
  ON emp
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF UPDATING AND :NEW.sal < :OLD.sal THEN
    :NEW.sal := :OLD.sal;  -- restore original salary
  ELSIF DELETING THEN
    raise_application_error(-20500, 'You cannot delete records from emp');
  END IF;
END test;
```

Comment: You are right, but I have figured out that trigger won't work in case of updating several records. For example if I want change sal for all people with Johnson surname - WHERE emp_name = 'Johnson' if new salary will be lower for one of them trigger will block whole update. How can I protect from that?